# Creating new columns in dataframe that will be based on conditions and on another column's values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'X':[0,0,10,10,10,15,20,50,50,55,80,100,1500]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    X
0   0
1   0
2   10
3   10
4   10
5   15
6   20
7   50
8   50
9   55
10  80
11  100
12  1500
```

In addition, I have these 4 parameters:

```
A_Bucket=10
B_Bucket=50
C_Bucket=100
D_Bucket=300
```

X -> Running Column.
I would like to create 4 new columns (A,B,C,D) that will be based on the X column and based on the 4 parameters, by the following logic:
A -> add the amount from X till A will reach the same value as A_Bucket. Once it will reach it, we need to move to the next column.
B -> add the amount from X till B will reach the same value as B_Bucket. Once it will reach it, we need to move to the next column.
The same goes for C and D.
The sum of A,B,C and D should always be less or equal to X.

The output should look like this:

```
       
Index  X    A   B   C   D
1      0    0   0   0   0
2      0    0   0   0   0
3     10   10   0   0   0
4     10   10   0   0   0
5     10   10   0   0   0
6     15   10   5   0   0
7     20   10  10   0   0
8     50   10  40   0   0
9     50   10  40   0   0
10    55   10  45   0   0
11    80   10  50  20   0
12   100   10  50  40   0
13  1500   10  50 100   300
```

It's worth mentioning that this is just an example and I need to create a lot more columns by this logic so I need it to be effective as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `where` clause by subtracting the total amount of current value from X every time.

```
df = df.set_index("X")

for x, y in zip("ABCD", [A_Bucket, B_Bucket, C_Bucket, D_Bucket]):
    df[x] = (df.index-df.sum(1)).where((df.index-df.sum(1)).le(y), y)

print (df)

         A     B      C      D
X                             
0      0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
0      0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
10    10.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
10    10.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
10    10.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
15    10.0   5.0    0.0    0.0
20    10.0  10.0    0.0    0.0
50    10.0  40.0    0.0    0.0
50    10.0  40.0    0.0    0.0
55    10.0  45.0    0.0    0.0
80    10.0  50.0   20.0    0.0
100   10.0  50.0   40.0    0.0
1500  10.0  50.0  100.0  300.0
```